# How to update hidden$= attribute in a Polymer Model?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jetepejixo/1/edit?html,console,output), you're supposed to be able to see '4' rendered when you click the 'show more' button. The console logs the change to the my-element's model but the DOM doesn't update. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>polymer</title>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <button on-click="_dosomething">show more</button>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myItems}}" >
      <div hidden$="{{_isItemHidden(item, shownItems)}}">{{item}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    Polymer({
     is: 'my-element',
     ready: function() {
      this.myItems = [1,2,3,4,5];
      this.shownItems = [1,2,3]
     }, 
      _dosomething: function(){
        console.log(this.shownItems);
        this.push('shownItems', 4);
        console.log(this.shownItems);
      },
      _isItemHidden: function(item, shownItems) {
        return !shownItems.some(function (i) {return i == item});
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<my-element></my-element>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a new array each time, you can observe the array change by using a wildcard * inside the computed binding (read it from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#deep-observation)).

So your binding becomes to -

```
<div hidden$="{{_isItemHidden(item, shownItems.*)}}">{{item}}</div>
```

And your computing function now should be -

```
_isItemHidden: function(item, e) {
    return !e.base.some(function (i) { return i == item });
}
```

Check out an updated jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/jekugunano/edit?html,console,output).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [simple](http://jsbin.com/hufonigaci/edit?html,console,output), to get the system to be notified and forth the `_isItemHidden`function to be called you have to update the reference of `shownItems` array.

```
this.shownItems.push(4);

this.set('shownItems', this.shownItems.slice());
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confused as to why the API is this way - I thought the point of this.push/pop/set/etc. was that using the Polymer-provided array mutators allowed the mutation of the array to be observed. But it sounds like instead you have to use this.set on a whole new array (in this situation, provided by slice()).

Comment: why only "this.showItems.slice()" works and "this.showItems" doesn't ??? Even both output the same value.